# How to configure a GUI extension

Tags: tridion

I would like to make my data extender configurable through a config file. I found out there is a node 'customconfiguration' in the editor config file. I'm guessing this can be used to configure the behaviour of an extension. Is there a way to access that customconfiguration node from C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know that it applies for a data extender but I read custom config from a Model config using the following code:

```cs
using System.Xml;
using Tridion.Web.UI;
using Tridion.Web.UI.Core;

namespace Custom.Model
{
    public class Configuration
    {
        public static string GetConfigString(string configItem) {
            XmlDocument customConfiguration = ConfigurationManager.Models["Custom.Model"].CustomXml;
            XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
            ns.AddNamespace("c", Constants.EDITOR_CONFIG_NAMESPACE);
            XmlNode node = customConfiguration.SelectSingleNode("//c:customconfiguration/c:clientconfiguration/c:" + configItem, ns);
            string configValue = node != null ? node.InnerText : "";

            return configValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Rather than using ConfigurationManager.Models you can use ConfigurationManager.Editors to get to your Editor config. You reference the Model or Editor by the name specified in the System.config where you enable the extension, e.g. CME as defined in the example below.

```xml
<editor name="CME">
  <installpath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\web\WebUI\Editors\CME\</installpath>
  <configuration>Configuration\CME.config</configuration>
  <vdir>CME</vdir>
</editor>
```

Answer (score 2):

Configuration file in the WebRoot/Configuration folder is general configuration file for CME application, "Core" configuration file. Besides that there are configuration files for each Editor and Model in CME application. Those configuration files has "customconfiguration" section, which is accessible from the ConfigurationManager.

When you'll create your DataExtenderr, you'll need to create new extension Model. And configuration file for that Model, where you can fill customconfiguration section with information you need.